Проблема с отображением текста и элементов в Xamarin Forms на экране смартфона и эмулятора
Я столкнулся с проблемой в Xamarin Forms, из-за которой отображается не весь текст, а также элементы, находящиеся за пределами экрана, не отображаются. Вращение смартфона временно устраняет проблему, пока данные не будут перезагружены или приложение не обновит их. Эта проблема возникает как в эмуляторе, так и на реальном смартфоне, причем в разных проектах.
Отображение при загрузке:

Отображение при изменении ориентации:

Отображение при возврате ориентации:

Я уже пытался решить проблему, используя:
Changing the font size: Table Label.Font Size = Device.GetNamedSize(Name Size.Small, type of(Label));
Using lineBreakMode: Table Label.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode.WordWrap;
Setting HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions: Table Label.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand; TableLabel.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
xaml code:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Raspisanie.MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Button Text="ChangingSides" Clicked="ChangingSidesClicked"/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <Button Text="Previous table" Clicked="OnPreviousClicked"/>
                    <Button Text="Next table" Clicked="OnNextClicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="TableLabel" Text="The table will be displayed here"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>

cs code:
string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
TableLabel.Text = responseData;

cs does not affect the display, because display problems occur when only elements are created

Метод .ForceLayout() в Xamarin.Forms используется для принудительного обновления макета элемента и его дочерних элементов.
Когда вы вызываете этот метод, он заставляет элемент пройти через процесс макетирования снова, что может быть полезно, если вы изменили свойства элемента, которые влияют на его размер или расположение, и хотите, чтобы изменения вступили в силу немедленно.
Вот пример использования: yourView.ForceLayout();
Этот метод может быть полезен в ситуациях, когда автоматическое обновление макета не происходит, и вам нужно вручную инициировать перерасчет макета.
